# Slickgrid dataview row update with save button?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a dataview with several columns, 2 of which are editable, incoming JSON data is bound to this.  I also have an additional column at the end with a save button.

If these two fields are edited and I click the save button I'd like to get the values in this row inclusive of the 2 new values from these edited fields. Currently when I click the save button the row only contains the original values, not the updated values.

I guess I am missing something fundamental with slickgrids, do I need to save this row first for the new values to become accessible? I've tried some of the built in methods from the github documentation but cant get this to work.

E.g.
when cell is clicked:

```
if (col.id == 'saved'){console.log(row)}
```

The end goal to compare the old and new row to see if there are differences, can someone please explain what I need to do here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The values are saved to the rows by the individual cell editor `applyValue` method, eg:

```
this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
  item[args.column.field] = state;
};
```

The trick is that the editor only commits values when you exit it. That means if you click a 'Save' button in a different column, this may not trigger an editor and the value in the previous still-active editor may not be saved (if a new editor is triggered, any active editor value is committed).
In this situation, call

```
grid.getEditorLock().commitCurrentEdit()
```

immediately in your Save function.

In terms of the old and new rows, you'll probably need to save a copy of the row somehow on first edit, for later comparison. True client side multi row editing with row deletion and addition is a complex beast, and not easy to tame. You're better off using a library if you can.